# Linux file command doesn't classify this as a Python script

Tags: python, linux, file

I have a Python script on which I use the Linux `file` command to classify as such in another script. Unfortunately, it is interpreted as `C++ source, ASCII text`. The start of the script looks like the following in this case:

```
#!/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import stat
import re

settings = {}

template_file = None
output_file = None

template_filename = None
output_filename = None
```

However, if I put the `None` assignments in an `if True` block, `file` properly detects this as `a /bin/python3 script, ASCII text executable`:

```
#!/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import stat
import re

settings = {}

if True:
    template_file = None
    output_file = None

    template_filename = None
    output_filename = None
```

Here is my terminal output:

```
$ cat python_as_cpp.py
#!/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import stat
import re

settings = {}

template_file = None
output_file = None

template_filename = None
output_filename = None
$ file python_as_cpp.py
python_as_cpp.py: C++ source, ASCII text
$ cat python_as_python.py
#!/bin/python3

import os
import sys
import stat
import re

settings = {}

if True:
    template_file = None
    output_file = None

    template_filename = None
    output_filename = None
$ file python_as_python.py
python_as_python.py: a /bin/python3 script, ASCII text executable
$ file -v
file-5.11
magic file from /etc/magic:/usr/share/misc/magic
```

What would cause the first code sample to be detected as C++?

Comment: On my system, both scripts are being detected as python 3 scripts. Is it like are you using some outdated version of the file command?

Comment: Can you share your terminal output with `file <your-above-code.py>` for both the cases? For both, the above code snippets will output `python3 script, ASCII text executable`

Answer (score 0):

We had an old version of `file` installed. Upgrading to [v5.39](ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file) fixed the problem.